# What type of competitive gaming is available to the public TF2 Community?

Tags: team-fortress-2, competitive-gaming

I'm semi-interested in the TF2 competitive community, possibly even getting involved in playing in a league at the entry level.  As such, I am looking for a competitive group that allows pub-level players to compete (both in terms of skill and in terms of access).

What types of leagues/communities are there that would allow a base-level gamer, with little competitive experience, to participate in a TF2 tournament?

I'm aware that there are different types of competitive TF2 - Highlander, 6v6, et cetera, and some rather goofy ones too.  The exact format isn't my primary concern so much as knowing what leagues/groups allow regular Joe Shmoe to enter.

Comment: @Assylum Actually random chance factors like crits and damage spread can be turned off for competitive play.  I know this for a fact.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Official Team Fortress Wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Competitive_play#Organizations) has names of some organizations that do league play.  If you are in North America, the [ESEA](http://play.esea.net) has an [open division](http://play.esea.net/index.php?s=league&d=standings&division_id=1337) and pick up games for players of all skill levels.

These leagues may run the [Standard competitive format](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Standard_competitive_format), which is a 6 on 6 match with crits off and team composition limiting (only 2 scouts on a team at one time, etc.) and fixed weapon spread; [Highlander](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Highlander_(Competitive)), which is a 9 on 9 match with the same rules as SCF, but only 1 player per class per team; and fun competitions like [Ultiduo](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Ultiduo) or [Basketball](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Basketball).

Due to the decrease in popularity in competitive play, the [ESL shut down their TF2 ladders](http://www.esl.eu/eu/tf2/news/192933/) on May 5th, 2012.

Comment: Do mention the ESL leagues.

Comment: @Edeph Added information! :)